# Looking for UK visa refusal stories and advice

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, family, working-visas

I'm a journalist for two UK national newspapers. I'm compiling an article about the difficulties faced by foreign nationals in getting UK visas – the hurdles to jump over, the endless documentation to compile, the ease with which one can be refused on technicalities – especially for something as overtly "simple" as a visitor visa.

I am interested both in hearing the stories of those who have been refused, and hearing the advice and wise counsel of the many (clearly well-informed) people on this site who offer answers, and who can perhaps shed some light on common problems faced/common mistakes made, etc.

I apologise if this is the wrong forum for this appeal, or if there is a proper section in which to ask it – but I cannot work out how else to ask. Without 'reptutation' points, I cannot even comment under individual questions. If you're interested, it'd be great to hear more from you.

Thank you,

Kieron

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a travel question.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately we only allow travel questions, so your specific query is off-topic. Please try another forum.

Comment: As in "try a different website other than travel.stackexchange"? Or "try a different part of this site"? Is there somewhere else on this site I can interact with potential visitors about their stories, and with experts about their professional advice? There doesn't seem to be a way to DM anyone.

Comment: Our only user-to-user platform for personal interactions is https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here. You cannot send DMs, but you may leave a note for other users. Otherwise please try a different forum focused on visa refusals.

Comment: The problem is that we are a Q&A website, not a traditional forum. Questions which cannot be answered directly have to be closed. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Unfortunately, I can't comment at the chatroom either as I need 20 reputation points ... by the time I've accrued 20 points, I'll be past my copy deadline. Frustrating, as I'm sure there are lots of people here with great stories to tell.

Comment: @Kieron Try http://www.immigrationboards.com/ they have certain threads dedicated for user to write their experiences.

Comment: by the end of this weekend you will have the required rep to chat, or you can visit META http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/ where you are  already over the rep hurdle.

Comment: @Kieron There are currently 4378 questions on this site tagged [tag:visas].  [876 of those](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas+uk) are UK-specific.  You might find some stories among those.  Otherwise, you may have better luck with this query on reddit.

Comment: You can easily enough find people who will tell you anything. But it's often questionable whether what they tell you bears any resemblance to reality. Of the hundreds of UK visa refusals we've seen here, I'm convinced that a significant number of them weren't genuine visitors and were trying to enter the UK via deception. Many others made serious but avoidable mistakes in their visa applications. But I can't recall a single refusal that was inappropriate given their individual circumstances.

Comment: @MichaelHampton nice one. Insightful. Plus about 100% of the refusals in our archives were predictable at the outset. It means before they even gave biometrics and submitted their stuff their applications were DOOMED because of evidential shortfall or funds parking or whatever. But these things do not reach the media and hence the OP is wasting his time here.

Comment: Thank you all. I realise it's off-topic for these boards, so I appreciate all of your input. If any of you are professionals on immigration issues and are happy to discuss the current landscape, feel free to drop me a line on Skype at kieron.shaw

Comment: @gerrit — yep, I've read a lot of those stories. It's what made me interested in speaking to those people and finding out more. Unfortunately I have no way of contacting them directly (or indirectly, via comments, as it's outside the rules.)

Comment: @MichaelHampton – it's a fair point and I don't doubt for a second that there are many with bad intentions. My angle is not "everyone's being unfairly refused, it's outrageous", more that the rules (while understandably stringent) are SO stringent in such specific ways that there are sad cases who have genuine reasons for visiting and get denied. My Tunisian girlfriend is one: She just wants to come to the UK to take an exam and improve her professional credentials. But she cannot demonstrate sufficient home ties, so is routinely denied. Thus, what hope does she have of bettering her life?